# Using clothesline in the garden - what needs the most support?

Tags: support

So, a yet another windstorm came through this week and dropped a branch tree on my clothesline, ripped it right off the house!

I was planning repurposing the line on using to support my peas next year, but they're doing just fine on the front lines with just jute twine.  So I thought I'd ask what veggies could benefit the most from being propped up with the steel reinforced clothesline wire? I've got about 300 feet of it.

Answer (score 4):

**Personal experience:** Tomatoes do great when grown on a trellis structure made of wires.

Below are a few more candidates that would do well on such a trellis structure:

- Snap or Snow peas
- Cucumbers
- Pole beans
- Melons
- Winter squash

**Disclaimer:** The above list comes from a web site I helped transfer over to WordPress. See here, "[Growing More with Less Space](http://greengardeningstl.com/2010/02/01/growing-more-with-less-space/)" for the actual post containing the above listed *"candidates"*.

Answer (score 4):

Steel reinforced clothesline wire would be a good choice for supporting raspberries and other cane fruit, as well as grape vines.